# Passing a long string from SoftwareSerial to Serial

Tags: serial-port, arduino, gsm

I'm currently playing around with a [GPRS shield](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/GPRS_Shield_V2.0) on an Arduino Uno, for which I have to write raw AT commands over the `SoftwareSerial`. At the moment, I just want to be able to talk to the GPRS from my PC, so I've written a really basic program to send serial in two directions:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial GPRS(7, 8);

void setup()
{
  GPRS.begin(19200);
  Serial.begin(19200);
}

void loop()
{
  if (GPRS.available())
  {
    Serial.write(GPRS.read());
  }

  if (Serial.available())
  {
    GPRS.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

So the communication looks something like this:

```
         HW               SW           
+----+ Serial +-------+ Serial +------+
|    |        |       |        |      |
|    +-------->       +-------->      |
| PC |        |Arduino|        | GPRS |
|    <--------+       <--------+      |
|    |        |       |        |      |
+----+        +-------+        +------+
```

This seems to work fine for shorter commands:

```
AT+CPIN?

+CPIN: READY

OK
```

But I'm really interested in doing a [`NETSCAN`](http://signusx.com/sim900-scanning-all-visible-cell-towers-from-all-gsm-operators/) to see what networks are available. When I try it, I get this:

```
AT+CNETSCAN

------MOST SUITABLE CELL------
Operator:"YES OPTUS",MCC:505,75
```

And that's all. I pulled out a logic analyser to spy on the serial pins themselves, and it appears that the complete message is being sent back to the Arduino from the GPRS module perfectly okay - but for some reason, it gets cut off before it reaches my PC.

This is what the logic analyser sees over the SW (top two tracks) and HW (bottom tracks) serial lines:

[image]

So it appears that the entire GPRS response is being read by the Arduino before it starts to send anything back to the PC, and I assume that some sort of buffer has been overrun and I only get the start of the message.

So - how should I go about passing through long strings between serial ports like this? I assumed that using `if (X.available())` instead of `while` would alleviate any issues with long strings (because it appears that this way the two serial ports should take turns with one byte at a time), but is that assumption incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Excluding the AT+CNETSCAN line, the output is exactly 64 bytes, which is the size of the software serial buffer. So I think you are correct that it is a buffer overflow. I take it you initially tried `while (X.available())`. Are you sure you re-uploaded. It seems it should work with an if. I expect it isn't that simple, so perhaps you could try storing data read from Serial before you send it. That would alleviate potential conflicts between the two serial connections.

Comment: I've uploaded several variants, and all strangely give identical behaviour: the message is cut off in the same place even if I try to use a buffer, and even if the code looks like it should stop reading the software serial and start writing to hardware serial, all I get are the first 63 bytes.